# How to add events in the google calendar from website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I have an HTML page and I want to integrate google calendar and add event features to it. I am able to embed google calendar into my webpage but, I am unable to add events to the calendar from my webpage itself. Is it possible to implement this feature? Thanks!

[image: this is what I have added to the page]

Comment: Have you followed this guide [`Let site visitors save a calendar event`](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en)? In addition you can use the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api) via  [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) to build your own functionality

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be studying this and I have an aside in my book that can help you:

> dayClick : is executed when the user clicks on a day; normally, is
> used to display a window so that a form can be filled in with the data
> needed to create an appointment or calendar entry. The function it
> generates gives access to the value of the day, the event and the type
> of view that is activated, which allows us to perform different
> actions depending on whether it is selected in one view or another
> (for example, create an appointment by clicking on the week format,
> but only show the message in the view monthly).
>
> ```
> dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
>    alert('dia clicado: ' + date.format());
>    alert('Coordenadas: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
>    alert('Vista atual: ' + view.name);
>  }
> ```

Comment: If you have a new question, please [ask it as such](/questions/ask). Also, please mention the source of your book quote, because as it stands, it risks being deleted since [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).